# Let $W:= \{ f(x) \in R[x] \ni f(x) $ has a root in $[0,1] \}$. Does $W$ form a subspace of $R[x]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $W:= \{ f(x) \in R[x] \ni f(x) $ has a root in $[0,1] \}$. Does
>   $W$ form a subspace of $R[x]$?

So clearly, $ \; \alpha f$ $\in W \; \; \forall f \in W  \; \; \forall \alpha \in R$

But the problem is am facing is in proving $f+g \in W$ when $f,g \in W$

I don't really know if it is even true on not. I tried some simple examples, and they do satisfy above. But I am unable to see how to actually prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $x,1-x\in W$. Is it true or false that $x+(1-x)\in W$?